# Translate nd array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

In python I have a nd array like this:

```
0 0 1
1 0 1
0 1 1
0 0 0
```

I know that the first position is “a”, second is “b”, and so on.

How can I transform “ones” to “as”, “bs”, … ?

Nothing yet. Not a clue.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might want to use array indexing:

```
a = np.array([[0,0,1],
              [1,0,1],
              [0,1,1],
              [0,0,0]])

out = np.array(['a', 'b'])[a]
```

Output:

```
array([['a', 'a', 'b'],
       ['b', 'a', 'b'],
       ['a', 'b', 'b'],
       ['a', 'a', 'a']], dtype='<U1')
```

##### replacing sequential 1s by a/b/c…

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

out = np.r_[[' '], list(ascii_lowercase)
            ][np.where(a.ravel(), a.cumsum(), 0).reshape(a.shape)]
```

Output:

```
array([[' ', ' ', 'a'],
       ['b', ' ', 'c'],
       [' ', 'd', 'e'],
       [' ', ' ', ' ']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for a way to have the ones be a, b, c... sequentially, and leaving the zeros alone. I do admit the phrasing is very vague.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I was just wondering the same, added this alternative ;)